# What's MBR offset 0x1C3 and how can I edit it?

Tags: hex, offset, solid-state-drive, hex-editors, mbr

I posted this question on another website but no one was able to help me there until a user suggested I posted this question here. So...

My SSD has some trouble POSTING on my old GA-P35-DS3 motherboard if I try to use the Intel controller.

Apparently (after much googling) I found this is a bug on the BIOS that can be fixed by some quick editing of the MBR. The trouble is, I have no idea how I can go about doing this. I tried 010 Editor and HxD but I'm completely overwhelmed and, although I am able to open the disk, I can't find that particular "offset" (0x1C3).

If you are curious this post describes my issue (scenario 1) and the required steps to fix it: http://forum.giga-byte.co.uk/index.php?topic=8585.0

So, if someone could help me figure what an "offset" is and how I can find it with 010 Editor (or any other program you see fit) so I could fix these byes I would very much appreciate it! :)

EDIT: I've been looking around and I'm a bit confused if I should change these bytes: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/in2lt.png

Or these bytes:
j59ypS5.png (I need more rep to post the second like so you can just copy-paste this into the imgur URL)

Judging by its content the first option doesn't seem to make sense. But since the second option is only "00 00 00" for I don't know if it makes any sense either...

If someone could please help me I'd be forever grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Well.. I was able to figure it out by myself so I'll leave the answer here in case someone faces the same issue in the future.

1) I was opening a logical drive instead of a physical unit. That's why what I was seeing wasn't meeting my expectations.

2) I thought the "offset" was only referenced by the column by the left but no. Ox1C3 actually includes the column number as well. So I had to change the three bytes including 0x1C3 (0x1C4 and 0x1C5).

That was pretty much it. After that I saved the changes and rebooted my machine and after changing the SATA port everything was working as expected.